# declaring tuple with list of long in c#

Tags: c#

I want to declare a tuple that contains a boolean and a list of longs.

This is what I have but it's underlined red on the last List:

```
Tuple<bool, List<long>> TheTuple = new Tuple<bool,List<long>>(false, List<long>);
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: no, tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Try again. This time with *feeling.*

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: ohhhh, I tried again with the new keyword and it worked:) I had forgotten the new keyword. You should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Tuple<bool, List<long>> TheTuple = Tuple.Create(false, default(List<long>));
```

Note that it will set the `Item2` property of the tuple to null, which is perhaps not what you want. If you want to set it to an actual `List<long>`, use `new List<long>()`:

```
Tuple<bool, List<long>> TheTuple = Tuple.Create(false, new List<long>());
```

Comment: @frenchie, the default keyword isn't going to help you. The result of `default(T)` for a reference type is null. The tuple Item2 property is readonly. I imagine a tuple with a frozen null reference is not what you want.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, that's what I thought the OP wanted, but you're right, in the general case it would make more sense to put an actual instance of List<T>. However, a list is mutable, while a tuple is not, so there are philosophical reasons not to do that. The best thing to do would probably be to use a ReadOnlyCollection<T> instead of a List<T>.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a type decription to the constructor, you need to pass in a variable of that type. (could be a Doh! moment)